# Records Storage Scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want your Suggestions on this and i want to implement this functionality in a better way. I have a list of records and it will contain 200 to 300 records or even more and the records is unique for each user. When the user select the records need to update the selected record from the list but that will not update the database only the list. So my question is : To hold the records temproarily what should i use whether i use Session or Viewstate or something different.

kindly help me out with this...

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question so it is legible?

Comment: ok... Oded... I will do that...

Comment: Why not just use a database? If you don't want it to be the "main" tables, then ... Use a separate set of tables!

Comment: Sorry Marc i can't use tables. I am getting the records from the database when the user update a specific records it will go into another user Inbox but the current user want to see which records he has updated and i can't change anything in the database..

Comment: @rick right - hence my "main" point... But surely you can use a database storage metaphor for their uncommitted changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewstate has a big burden on requests and responses.  I would say simply: don't use that... for anything, in fact.

Session-state sounds more promising, but personally I'd be looking at using a database-approach here, even for the uncommitted data - just have some separate tables to represent the in-progress work, perhaps in a different db-schema, or an entirely different db.

I guess ultimately though, that is very little difference to using session-state (except: more formal). It is, however, easier to update individual records in a db than it is to load session, deserialize, edit the objects, serialize, and store as session.

Comment: ...is there really less overhead for DB use? Living objects will reside happily enough in Session, AFAIK.

Comment: @sq33G I always assume a non-trivial system (with trivial systems, almost anything will work) - thus more than one server, thus session-state probably centralized and serialized. In which case: yes - a SQL query to update 1 value is much faster. Even locally, it is usually serialized.